# Using Views: how to display all node edits made by user X while excluding the "first time created" nodes (original node revision)

Tags: 7, views, nodes

For my content type I have enabled support for revisions. When I make view it displays the revisions along with nodes created by user. Is there any way to get only the list of edited nodes. If user created node and then edited it, I just want to show users edits only.  please suggest?

**UPDATE EXPORT VIEWS CODE :**

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'tetstststst';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'tetstststst';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'tetstststst';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '200';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['id'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['quantity'] = '9';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = array(
  'title' => 'title',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default'] = '-1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['info'] = array(
  'title' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
);
/* Header: Global: Result summary */
$handler->display->display_options['header']['result']['id'] = 'result';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['result']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['result']['field'] = 'result';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['result']['content'] = 'Displaying  @total';
/* Relationship: Content revision: User */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['table'] = 'node_revision';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
/* Field: Content revision: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_1']['id'] = 'title_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_1']['table'] = 'node_revision';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_1']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_1']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_1']['alter']['path'] = '[link_to_revision] ';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_1']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_1']['link_to_node_revision'] = TRUE;
/* Field: Content: Updated date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['changed']['id'] = 'changed';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['changed']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['changed']['field'] = 'changed';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['changed']['date_format'] = 'long';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['changed']['second_date_format'] = 'long';
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Contextual filter: User: Uid */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['relationship'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_argument_type'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_argument_options']['user'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'link' => 'link',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'tetstststst';
```

**EXPORT VIEWS CODE** [**updated** - taken from oksana-c's example]:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'content_revisions';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node_revision';
$view->human_name = 'Content Revisions';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Content Revisions';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['perm'] = 'view revisions';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['id'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['quantity'] = '9';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = array(
  'timestamp' => 'timestamp',
  'title' => 'title',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default'] = '-1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['info'] = array(
  'timestamp' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'title' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
);
/* Relationship: Content revision: Content */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['vid']['id'] = 'vid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['vid']['table'] = 'node_revision';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['vid']['field'] = 'vid';
/* Relationship: Content revision: User */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['table'] = 'node_revision';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
/* Field: Content revision: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node_revision';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['link_to_node_revision'] = TRUE;
/* Field: Content revision: Updated date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['id'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['table'] = 'node_revision';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['field'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: Content revision: Updated date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['timestamp']['id'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['timestamp']['table'] = 'node_revision';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['timestamp']['field'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['timestamp']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Contextual filter: User: Uid */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['relationship'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_argument_type'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_argument_options']['user'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['created']['relationship'] = 'vid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['created']['operator'] = 'empty';

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block_1');
```

**RESULTS FROM UPDATED VIEW**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Just need list of all nodes edited by user. I am not sure what is unclear with question, please comment I can explain. By default node_revisions table store first revision whenever node is created but I need only edits made by user. So I just want to exclude that first revision which get created whenever any user creates node  and trying to get list of edits made by user. Thanks !

Comment: The problem is solved and many thanks to [oksana-c](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/49935/oksana-c) who made this working and really appreciate his efforts and starting discussion in chat !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Original answer was completely overridden as the embedded view export did not produce desired results. Below is the View Export that produced desired results and some insight on

> how to display all node edits made by user X while excluding the
>   "first time created" nodes (original node revision).

Here's a little **PROLOGUE**:

Every time the node is edited - a new revision is created (you can bring your revisioning methods one level up by installing Revisioning module). So essentially each edit is a revision including the original node version, which also has it's own revision number. Even though revision info ais accessible through Views, there is no default method to differentiate the Original Revision (revision where node was created first) from other revisions in Views. This is because there are no fields that you can query that will tell you that the revision is the original node version. The only field that one can use for differentiating original version from revisioned version is "Node's Created Date". Unfortunately we cannot query this field in Views when we use revisioning and the only way to filter out the original versions of nodes from a View is to compare "created" date and "updated date".

**SOLUTION:** 
This task requires a custom Views filter, which will query "created date" of each node and compare it with "updated date" from the node's revision.

The quick way of doing this is to install [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module and use Global:PHP filter in View to query and compare dates. ***Warning:*** Views PHP may affect View performance significantly depending on the amount of results that should be processed.

The right way of doing this is to create custom Views filter handler. Some info on it [here](https://www.phase2technology.com/blog/a-views-handler-the-easy-way/) and [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/123614/drupal-7-views-3-add-custom-filter-handler-for-an-existing-field).

So here it is - the updated View Export that displays all revisions + dates of user X while filtering out Original Node Version. This View requires Views PHP module.

```
    $view = new view();
$view->name = 'content_revisions';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node_revision';
$view->human_name = 'Content Revisions';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Content Revisions';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['perm'] = 'view revisions';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '200';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['id'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['quantity'] = '9';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = array(
  'timestamp' => 'timestamp',
  'title' => 'title',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default'] = '-1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['info'] = array(
  'timestamp' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'title' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
);
/* Relationship: Content revision: User */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['table'] = 'node_revision';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
/* Relationship: Content revision: Content */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['vid']['id'] = 'vid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['vid']['table'] = 'node_revision';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['vid']['field'] = 'vid';
/* Field: Content revision: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node_revision';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['link_to_node_revision'] = TRUE;
/* Field: Content revision: Nid */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['table'] = 'node_revision';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content revision: Updated date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['id'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['table'] = 'node_revision';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['field'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['date_format'] = 'custom';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['custom_date_format'] = 'm/d/y H:i:s T';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['second_date_format'] = 'long';
/* Sort criterion: Content revision: Updated date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['timestamp']['id'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['timestamp']['table'] = 'node_revision';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['timestamp']['field'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['timestamp']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Contextual filter: User: Uid */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['relationship'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_argument_type'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_argument_options']['user'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
/* Contextual filter: Content: Nid */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['relationship'] = 'vid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['default_argument_type'] = 'fixed';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
/* Filter criterion: Global: PHP */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['php']['id'] = 'php';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['php']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['php']['field'] = 'php';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['php']['use_php_setup'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['php']['php_filter'] = '$node = node_load($row->nid);
$timestamp_original = $node->created;
$timestamp_edit = $row->timestamp;
if ($timestamp_original != $timestamp_edit) { return FALSE; }
else return TRUE;';
```

Comment: Thanks for try I have voted 1 for your efforst and help. but when I tired more details it shows only revision created of own content not the revisions or edits made on nodes of other people or own.

Comment: that is weird. That same view for me shows title and the date of performed edit of all nodes that are edited by the user, whether nodes were created by that user or other users.  You said you tried to add more details to the view? Can you show the export of the modified view? And can you explain where you showing this view? I assume on user's profile, because otherwise Context Filter of User ID from URL wouldnt make much sense.

Comment: I have not done much changes but I have tried and I am very sure that its not showing all edits. Please let me know I am doing something wrong. I have updated question with view code. Thanks

Comment: Like in screenshot I passed uid 735 and it shows only 4 nodes but I have made revisions on few nodes now for testing by user login 735 so those edits are not displaying in my case. For more details when edit made on own link it displays but when edit made on others link it doesn't.

Comment: I have updated question with new export code which is showing all relevant edits, can you please look at that one to remove node created ie: first time created nodes as revision entery

Comment: Ok, I see that with my filter "Post Date = empty) the view doesnt show the last edit, so that filter will not work as the last edit has Post Date and all other archived revisions dont have it. So my version of the view needs work. Your updated code shows only last revision (can be either last edit or node that wasn't edited yet, but it is published) - because of the filter "Content Published: Yes". So you approach with filter "Publushed - Yes" will not work because it will not list "all" edits made by user.

Comment: Please clarify - you need to list ALL edits made by user even if it means that nodes with multiple edits will show up in your view multiple times? And also remove nodes that weren't edited at all (a.k.a. "first time created")?

Comment: yes your last comment is exactly I am after, need to show all edits wether on own node or o other users node's. Its not a problem if repeted node shown as those will be revisions and   And also remove nodes that weren't edited at all (a.k.a. "first time created"). Please suggest if we can make something like this.

Comment: updated the answer, hope it helps you to reach your goals

Comment: I am very thankful for your efforts, please let me what kind of filter I need to create as when I import view it gives this **Field handler node.number_of_revisions is not available.** , I have already installed views php and will make custom filter later as you mentioned. Is something I need to before importing this view, please suggest . Thanks!

Comment: I also do not have installed *Revisioning module* but just  in D7 content type I have checked that revisions are allowed for content type like in my screenshot in updated question. And all loged-in users ie: editors have permissions to make revisions.

Comment: I updated the answer again, my view contained some fields that Revisioning module provides. It is not necessary to install it to produce the results that you want. Try updated export

Comment: Thanks again ! this view worked but now one more problem occurred. It removed the user nodes which have no revisions ie: first time revision when node is created.  **Problem:  but now the nodes of user which have revisions ie: edited but by other users keep appearing in view. ie: Node created by user appear if someone else has edited his node.** Hope you can suggest something to solve this.

Comment: ie: logic to remove nodes which have not being edited worked but if node is edited by other users and not edited by owner or viewed user or current user, node keeps appearing.

Comment: The View that I attached is tested on two different websites with completely different configurations of modules and it works as expected. The problem you describing must be connected to your setup or your modifications on the view. Keep in mind that one User Id must be provided as context for this View to show edits of only one User.

Comment: Yes thanks again but I think I am not able to clear my point  , suppose user id 7 has node and we are currently viewing user 7 with our this view. Node of user 7 is not edited by himself but suppose user 8 edited it then the node is showing in current view although it's not edit made by user 7 please try like this. Ideal solution I think is to check uid of user made edit and current uid for which we fetch view. Hope I am able to clear my point. Again thanks for continued efforts , I am also trying. You really helping lot , I will soon mark accept to help others as well, once I got it on place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34439/discussion-between-oksana-c-and-jas).